# Get values for first or last object for a model in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

`Model.objects.all().values()` returns a list of object values.

`Model.objects.all().first()` - This just appears to print an object reference with `id` field attribute.

Is there a way to do something like: `Model.objects.all().first().values()`?

The following does the trick, but is there something for this purpose?
`Model.objects.filter(id=Model.objects.all().last().id).values()`

Comment: You can work with `Model.objects.all().values().first()`, since `.values()` returns a `QuerySet`, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the `.first()` after the `.values()`, since [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) does *not* return a list, but a `QuerySet` that is not evaluated unless you *consume* it.

You thus can query with:

```
Model.objects.values().first()
```

This will return a single dictionary, and the `.first()` will thus force evaluation.